# How to edit and refresh JSON data in an Android activity?

Tags: android, json

My Android application utilizes a backend API highly; basically, all of the information is queried from web server and rendered on Activities. So far, I've designed the application to be "read only".

For example, MainActivity first queries server for JSON data and shows the data in a listview. User can open a specific list item by clicking on it. The JSON data for an item is passed to the new activity (SubActivity) as a String representation of a JSONOBject (data.getObject(listItemPosition).toString()), so that no new query to the server need to be made.

However, now I'm facing a challenge as the second part of the application is under development: how to refresh data after it has been modified by user in an Activity. Lets say for example, MainActivity has a listing of images with image comment, and SubActivity shows single image, comment, and some additional information. Now I want to develop a function where user can edit the image comment in the SubActivity.

How should I deal with refreshing the data in MainActivity & SubActivity? Should I edit JSON objects directly (hard from SubActivity)? Should I somehow notify the MainActivity to reload the data? Any other best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using arraylists and customarrayadapters then yes you can notify the data object (and UI object) to refresh itself and update the view

you can edit JSON objects directly, its not like they are sacred, but JSONArrays can be kind of slow.

you can notify activities by doing `startActivityforResult` method and `onActivityResult` methods

do you need to update the server with this information? just make a new api call on the server that accepts this information

Comment: Yeah, server update part is okay (API call). startActivityResult would be one option, is it "standard" to use it for this kind of operation? About editing JSON objects, I think it's impossible to edit MainActivity JSON data from the SubActivity.